# Space Complexity of Python's itertools

Tags: python, combinations, subset-sum

I've tried to write a subset-sum solver but with better space complexity.

My idea is that if the statement `sum(jj) != target` returns true. 
It deletes the combination thus saving memory, *but I'm under the impression that the for loop must remember all combinations up till a target-sum is found.*

Or, python is already doing what I'm trying to do.

So here's what I got

```
import itertools
from itertools import combinations 


s=[2,3,4,6,7]

target = 5


for j in range(0, len(s)):
  for jj in combinations(s, j):
   if sum(jj) != target: 
     del(jj)
   else:
     print('yes', jj)
     quit()
```

*Output*

`yes (2, 3)`

Can python work with my idea instead of remembering all other combinations that "returned" a negative subset-sum?

Comment: itertools are lazy iterators they don't calculate values until they need them, then they're gone.

Comment: `del jj` has no effect here at all; it only deletes the local variable, but it is reassigned again on the next iteration.

Comment: @Mark Meyer So, O(1) space-complexity?

Comment: The space complexity is O(len(s)) to keep track of the current combination in order to be able to find the next one.

Comment: @kaya3 So basically it counts it. So wouldn't counting be a little faster than O(n)?

Answer (score 1):

What gives you the idea that a `for` will "remember" something?  It's only ambient storage is the loop index, `jj`.  Your approach is good for space complexity: you consider only one combination in each iteration.  `combinations` is a *generator*: it supplies the next combination *only* when you ask for it; until then, it merely holds its state and waits for your invocation.

`del(jj)` is dangerous: removing your loop index while the loop is active?  Remove that branch from your program; simply deal with the positive case and continue if warranted:

```
if sum(jj) == target:
    print(jj)
    break
```

Comment: `del` removes the variable from the current name space.  Since you're still using the variable ... you're saved only because of `for` semantics.

Comment: Technically, the `for` loop maintains a reference to the iterator, not just the current value from it. The iterator can be a generator with arbitrary state, and it's not impossible to write a generator which remembers all of its past outputs - it's just there is no reason to, so it doesn't.

Comment: @Kaya3 So its like counting (sorta) from 1 to any-number.  Its like we don't have to remember 100 numbers. But we can count from 1 to 100 in poly-space?

Comment: @TravisWells You seem to be confused about some things and it's hard to know what answer will clear up that confusion. Yes, like when you are counting you don't have to memorise all of the past numbers you counted, just remembering the current number is enough. But this has nothing to do with "poly-space" - even if you did remember all the numbers from 1 to n, that would still take polynomial space.

Comment: @kaya3 yes, the loop keeps a separate reference, rather than a variable name; the loop logic will continue to work with that reference.  Doing other things with the loop index will provide results that are occasionally amusing.